# Activerecord query with array in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a location table in my rails app which has four columns :-

| Id  | Longitude | Latitude | user_id

Now I have an array containing the list of user_ids. How can I write an active record query to select the last row of each user id. For example, if I have three user_ids in my array **[1,2,3]** I want the query to return just the last row corresponding to each user_id (lets assume entries for each user_id is present in the table) from the table.

So, far I am able to get all the rows corresponding to all the user_ids using this following query:

```
@ids = [1,2,3]
@locations = Location.where(user_id: ids)
```

How can I modify this activerecord query so that it returns only the last row corresponding to each user_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord - select first record from each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206809/activerecord-select-first-record-from-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
@ids = [1,2,3]
@locations = @ids.map {|id| [Location.where(user_id: id).last.location,User.find(id).name]}
#This would give you something like this: [["US",XYZ],["IND","ABC"]]
```

Comment: Doing a little bit of editing like **@locations = @ids.map {|id| Location.where(user_id: id).last}** 
makes this solution work. I want to ask one more thing, how can I add user name corresponding to the user_id (User has_many Locations relationship  in the response ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer, let me know if it's working

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `User` model that has many locations, you could start from the user model and use the association to get to your last location for each user.

```
User.where(:id => @ids).includes(:locations).collect { |u| u.locations.last }
```

- `User.where(:id => @ids)` returns your collection of user objects.
- `includes(:locations)` eager loads the associated locations, so we don't run into an `n+1` problem.
- `collect { |u| u.locations.last }` maps the last associated location into an array